# Correction Vector (residual unbalance vector) Of Four Vectors in matlab

Tags: vectors, matlab

these vectors (A,B,C and D) achieved from balancing machine. (single plane) I put a mass (16.7 gram) at 219, 309, 39 and 129 degrees on balancing system and get A,B,C and D as a results. so it's means our balancing machine has a lag (or limp) as known "residual unbalance vector". and I trying to find the lag (or limp) vector that could be as corrective vector.
I have four vectors and I'm trying to find corrective vector.

```
A = [16.54 219.7];
B = [16.82 309.8];
C = [16.86 40.3];
D = [16.74 128.9];
```

the corrective vector must to change those vectors (A,B,C,D) to these:

```
AR = [16.7 219.7];
BR = [16.7 309.7];
CR = [16.7 39.7];
DR = [16.7 129.7];
```

first number is magnitude and second number of each vectors is phase in degree.
I changed this vectors to to coordinates (x,y) to find polygon and calculate the centroid of this polygon (my idea to find correction vector):

```
ax = A(1) * cosd(A(2));
ay = A(1) * sind(A(2));
bx = B(1) * cosd(B(2));
by = B(1) * sind(B(2));
cx = C(1) * cosd(C(2));
cy = C(1) * sind(C(2));
dx = D(1) * cosd(D(2));
dy = D(1) * sind(D(2));

u = [ax bx cx dx];
v = [ay by cy dy];
polyin = polyshape(u,v);
[A,B] = centroid(polyin);
```

after calculation, I subtracted each first vectors from A,B:

```
rax =  ax-A;
ray =  ay-B;

rbx =  bx-A;
rby =  by-B;

rcx =  cx-A;
rcy =  cy-B;

rdx =  dx-A;
rdy =  dy-B;


U = [rax rbx rcx rdx];
V = [ray rby rcy rdy];
```

at the end i calculated result vectors (change coordinates to vectors):

```
am = sqrt(rax * rax + ray * ray);
ap = rad2deg(atan2(ray,rax));

bm = sqrt(rbx * rbx + rby * rby);
bp = rad2deg(atan2(rby,rbx));

cm = sqrt(rcx * rcx + rcy * rcy);
cp = rad2deg(atan2(rcy,rcx));

dm = sqrt(rdx * rdx + rdy * rdy);
dp = rad2deg( atan2(rdy,rdx));

mag = [am bm cm dm]
phase = [ap bp cp dp]
```

but results are:

```
mag   = 16.6878   16.8457   16.7120   16.7132
phase = 219.79    309.3     40.21     129.40
```

is there any idea to find best correction vector?
thanks.

[first vectors and result vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3T5l.jpg)

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of what you want to do - are you basically trying to write your vectors in polar coordinates? I don't think "corrective" vector is a common term, so it may be a mistranslation into English.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. these vectors (A,B,C and D) achieved from balancing machine. (single plane) we put a mass (16.7 gram)  at 219, 309, 39 and 129 degrees on balancing system and get A,B,C and D as a results. so it's means our balancing machine has a lag ( or limp) and we trying to find the lag (or limp) vector that could be as corrective vector.

Comment: So you want to figure out the difference in force based on the object's position on the scale?

Comment: yes, i want to find "residual unbalance" vector. if i find this vector i could correct the A,B,C and D vectors. (by summation or subtraction with correction vector.